# Evaluating Spin 1 matrices $S_x*S_y$ in terms of $S_+$ and $S_-$ basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-chains

I am a beginner to spin algebra. I am trying to represent $S_x*S_y$ in terms of $S_+$ and $S_-$ basis. What would this representation look like? I know that the Pauli properties for spin 1/2 does not apply to Spin 1 matrices.

Comment: what does * mean here?  Where does the spin-1 properties enter?

Comment: It means just multiply. I meant the matrices when I said properties.

Comment: Have you tried writing the reverse of $\hat S_\pm = S_x\pm i S_y$ and multiplying?